# Android Push notifications & getting device ID

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have recently created an iPhone application that will receive push notifications. 
I do this using my own server etc rather then using a third party client.

I now need to recreate the application so it is suitable for android.

As i have noticed the process of doing this in android compared to apple is some what different.

I need to take the device token and store the token from within our database.

I then don't understand how it will still work.

I have been looking up google cloud messaging but its really confused me, does any one know of any good tutorials i could follow as im not a avid android user and i haven't been learning java for long.

Im desperate to find out how to this.

First thing i would like to do is to find out the device id and print it out on the console or in my log cat and i cant do this, can any one please help me i will be eternally grateful.

Thank You.

Comment: Hi @Sophia_xoox, did you get the solution for this?? if so, can you share it here?

Comment: @raja sorry no one ever got back to me 